# Codeigniter append existing session

Tags: codeigniter

How to append a new value to the existing session in codeigniter without retrieve session data and reassign the values?

I have a session like this:

$sess = array('a'=>1,'b'=>1);

$this->session->set_userdata('my_session',$sess);

I want to append an array 'array('p'=>1,'q'=>2)' to my existing session named 'my_session'

Any idea?

(if not clear please comment)

Comment: Shayan Husaini gave you the answer you are looking for. I suggest read the documentation of CI and particular the section about Sessions http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Please explain your question more clearly, preferably with code. It's unclear what the problem is, since adding data to the session is so trivially simple. Did you mean to append a specific *value* already in the session with some more data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use
 `$this->session->set_userdata('variable_name', 'some_value');`
if your variable already exists in the session its value will be reassigned other wise a new variable will be created.